# How to build case-insensitive SPARQL filter?

Tags: sparql

I am trying to build some queries with SPARQL searching by the label field without case sensivity.

I start from this query which works fine:

```
SELECT distinct ?concepto, ?objeto, ?label WHERE {?concepto rdfs:comment ?objeto. ?concepto rdfs:label ?label. FILTER (lang(?label) = 'es' && ?label='Francisco de Quevedo'@es && (lang(?objeto) = 'es' || lang(?objeto) = 'en'))} LIMIT 100
```

But if I try to add a FILTER constraint to make the query case insensitive, it doesn't work:

```
SELECT distinct ?concepto, ?objeto, ?label WHERE {?concepto rdfs:comment ?objeto. ?concepto rdfs:label ?label. FILTER (lang(?label) = 'es' && lcase(str(?label))='francisco de quevedo'@es && (lang(?objeto) = 'es' || lang(?objeto) = 'en'))} LIMIT 100
```

Diferent options to do queries searching by labels searching general concepts (i.e: Galaxy, Mountain, Francisco de Quevedo). I need to identify only one object that contains this topics and I don't know previously if the label is registered in lower or upper case.

Next code doesn't work (it's a heavy query, and take all the objects that CONTAIN tha word Galaxy:

```
SELECT distinct ?concepto ?objeto ?label WHERE {?concepto rdfs:comment ?objeto. ?concepto rdfs:label ?label FILTER (lang(?label) = 'es' && (lang(?objeto) = 'es' || lang(?objeto) = 'en') && regex(?label, "Galaxia","i"))} LIMIT 100
```

This other code works fine, I obtain the correct object but I need to know exactly how it is write (upper or lower case):

```
SELECT distinct ?concepto ?objeto ?label WHERE { ?concepto rdfs:comment ?objeto. ?concepto rdfs:label ?label FILTER (lang(?label) = 'es' && (lang(?objeto) = 'es' || lang(?objeto) = 'en') && ?label = "Galaxia"@es)} LIMIT 1000
```

And the last one is ok with the performance but obtain lots of results, I need to obtain only the object Galaxy searching by label in Spanish:

```
SELECT distinct ?concepto ?objeto ?label WHERE {?concepto rdfs:comment ?objeto. ?concepto rdfs:label ?label. ?label bif:contains '"Galaxia"' FILTER (lang(?label) = 'es' && (lang(?objeto) = 'es' || lang(?objeto) = 'en'))} LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 3):

applying `STR(?label)` results in the language tag being removed so remove the `@es` from the string your comparing to.

Comment: `lcase(str(?label))` removes the language tag and results in a plain string, thus, it can't match the literal `'francisco de quevedo'@es`. In addition, don't forget the timeout in the web interface, i.e. it will return anything found until the given timeout

Comment: And please, use the fulltext index of Virtuoso, your queries would have to scan all labels and do string comparison - that is too slow: `SELECT distinct ?concepto ?objeto ?label WHERE {
?concepto rdfs:comment ?objeto. 
?concepto rdfs:label ?label. ?label bif:contains '"francisco de quevedo"' 
FILTER (lang(?label) = 'es' && (lang(?objeto) = 'es' || lang(?objeto) = 'en'))} LIMIT 100`